# Running gdal_contrast_stretch command in Windows

Tags: gdal

I am trying to run a GDAL command that converts the bit depth while applying a stretch function (gdal_contrast_stretch -ndv 0 -linear-stretch 70 30 ./tmp/b2-projected.tif ./tmp/b2-8bit.tif). However, I can't find a way to do it in MS Windows. I have checked the precompiled GDAL binaries in [GISinternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php) and they don't carry the above mentioned command.
If not available, what do you guys suggest to use to get the same output using CLI tools in Windows?

Comment: gdal_contrast_stretch isn't a part of GDAL, but rather is a utility for use in conjunction with GDAL; which is why I assume it's not available with the precompiled GDAL available at GISinternals.

Comment: It's here [in Github](https://github.com/gina-alaska/dans-gdal-scripts).Unfortunately there isn't a makefile available for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can get a similar result using gdal_translate and the -scale option.

> -scale [src_min src_max [dst_min dst_max]]:

Something like the following (also specifying the output type if you want it to differ from the input type):

`gdal_translate -scale 0 12000 -ot byte ./tmp/b2-projected.tif ./tmp/b2-8bit.tif`

You will need to determine the appropriate values of source min & source max based on your input image.

[gdal_translate Documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)